# Dangers of stack overflow and segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I'm trying to understand how the objects (variables, functions, structs, etc) work in c++. In this case I see there are basically two ways of storing them: the stack and the heap. Accordingly, whenever the heap storage is used it needs to be dealocated manually, but if the stack is used, then the dealocation is automaticcally done. so my question is related to the kinds of problems that bad practice might cause the program itself or to the computer. For example:

1.- Let'suposse that I run a program with a recursion solution by using an infinite iteration of functions. Theoretically the program crashes (stack overflow), but does it cause some trouble to the computer itself? (To the RAM maybe or to the SO).

2.- What happens if I forget to dealocate memory on the heap. I mean, does it just cause trouble to the program or it is permanent to the computer in general. I mean it might be that such memory could not be used never again or something.

3.- What are the problems of getting a segmentation fault (the heap).

Some other dangers or cares relevant to this are welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Accordingly, whenever the stack storage is used it needs to be
>   dealocated manually, but if the heap is used, then the dealocation is
>   automaticcally done.

When you use stack - local variables in the function - they are deallocated automatically when the function ends (returns).

When you allocate from the heap, the memory allocated remains "in use" until it is freed. If you don't do that, your program, if it runes for long enough and keep allocating "stuff", will use all memory available to it, and eventually fail.

Note that "stackfault" is almost impossible to recover from in an application, because the stack is no longer usable when it's full, and most operations to "recover from error" will involve using SOME stack memory. The processor typically has a special trap to recover from stack fault, but that lands insise the operating system, and if the OS determines the application has run out of stack, it often shows no mercy at all - it just "kills" the application immediately.

> 1.- Let'suposse that I run a program with a recursion solution by using an infinite iteration of functions. Theoretically the program
>   crashes (stack overflow), but does it cause some trouble to the
>   computer itself? (To the RAM maybe or to the SO).

No, the computer itself is not harmed by this in and of itself. There may of course be data-loss if your program wasn't saving something that the user was working on.

Unless the hardware is very badly designed, it's very hard to write code that causes any harm to the computer, beyond loss of stored data (of course, if you write a program that fills the entire hard disk from the first to the last sector, your data will be overwritten with whatever your program fills the disk with - which may well cause the machine to not boot again until you have re-installed an operating system on the disk). But RAM and processors don't get damaged by bad coding (fortunately, as most programmers make mistakes now and again).

> 2.- What happens if I forget to dealocate memory on the heap. I mean, does it just cause trouble to the program or it is permanent to the
>   computer in general. I mean it might be that such memory could not be
>   used never again or something.

Once the program finishes (and most programs that use "too much memory" does terminate in some way or another, at some point).

Of course, how well the operating system and other applications handle "there is no memory at all available" varies a little bit. The operating system in itself is generally OK with it, but some drivers that are badly written may well crash, and thus cause your system to reboot if you are unlucky. Applications are more prone to crashing due to there not being enough memory, because allocations end up with NULL (zero) as the "returned address" when there is no memory available. Using address zero in a modern operating system will almost always lead to a "Segmentation fault" or similar problem (see below for more on that).

But these are extreme cases, most systems are set up such that one application gobbling all available memory will in itself fail before the rest of the system is impacted - not always, and it's certainly not guaranteed that the application "causing" the problem is the first one to be killed if the OS kills applications simply because they "eat a lot of memory". Linux does have a "Out of memory killer", which is a pretty drastic method to ensure the system can continue to work [by some definition of "work"].

> 3.- What are the problems of getting a segmentation fault (the heap).

Segmentation faults don't directly have anything to do with the heap. The term segmentation fault comes from older operating systems (Unix-style) that used "segments" of memory for different usages, and "Segmentation fault" was when the program went outside it's allocated segment. In modern systems, the memory is split into "pages" - typically 4KB each, but some processors have larger pages, and many modern processors support "large pages" of, for examble, 2MB or 1GB, which is used for large chunks of memory.

Now, if you use an address that points to a page that isn't there (or isn't "yours"), you get a segmentation fault. This, typically will end the application then and there. You can "trap" segmentation fault, but in all operating systems I'm aware of, it's not valid to try to continue from this "trap" - but you could for example store away some files to explain what happened and help troubleshoot the problem later, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, your understanding of stack/heap allocations is backwards: stack-allocated data is automatically reclaimed when it goes out of scope. Dynamically-allocated data (data allocated with `new` or `malloc`), which is generally heap-allocated data, must be manually reclaimed with `delete`/`free`. However, you can use C++ destructors ([RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)) to automatically reclaim dynamically-allocated resources.

Secondly, the 3 questions you ask have nothing to do with the C++ language, but rather they are only answerable with respect to the environment/operating system you run a C++ program in.  Modern operating systems generally isolate processes so that a misbehaving process doesn't trample over OS memory or other running programs.  In Linux, for example, each process has its own address space which is allocated by the kernel.  If a misbehaving process attempts to write to a memory address outside of its allocated address space, the operating system will send a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) which usually aborts the process. Older operating systems, such as MS-DOS, didn't have this protection, and so writing to an invalid pointer or triggering a stack overflow could potentially crash the whole operating system.

Likewise, with most mainstream modern operating systems (Linux/UNIX/Windows, etc.), memory leaks (data which is allocated dynamically but never reclaimed) only affect the process which allocated them.  When the process terminates, all memory allocated by the process is reclaimed by the OS.  But again, this is a feature of the operating system, and has nothing to do with the C++ language.  There may be some older operating systems where leaked memory is never reclaimed, even by the OS.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Well, so I think there is nothing to worry about while programming. I mean the worst thing that can happen is the crashing of the program, then I need to correct the mistake and see what happen. Is it so? I had this question above all because I was scared of something bad that I might produce to my computer.

Comment: @Daniela Diaz, as I said, it depends on the OS you're using. But most likely the answer is yes: usually the worst thing that can happen is crashing the program. (However, even with a modern OS, programs which leak or allocate too much memory can cause the whole computer to perform badly due to page faults.)

Comment: The one comment I would add is, though most modern systems should handle memory leaks gracefully, they still happen to missbehave when you allocate literally whole allocable memory. It is kind of the same when you use whole diskspace. Sometimes some crucial services handle such situations poorly. Honestly I do not know many programmers that always check is malloc/new failed and handle it gracefully. EDIT: Now I see Mats' answer covered it too.

Answer (score 0):

`1.- Let'suposse that I run a program with a recursion solution by using an infinite iteration of functions. Theoretically the program crashes (stack overflow), but does it cause some trouble to the computer itself? (To the RAM maybe or to the SO).`

A stack overflow should not cause trouble neither to the Operating System nor to the computer. Any modern OS provides an isolated address space to each process. When a process tries to allocate more data in its stack than space is available, the OS detects it (usually via an exception) and terminates the process. This guarantees that no other processes are affected.

`2.- What happens if I forget to dealocate memory on the heap. I mean, does it just cause trouble to the program or it is permanent to the computer in general. I mean it might be that such memory could not be used never again or something.`

It depends on whether your program is a long running process or not, and the amount of data that you're failing to deallocate. In a long running process (e.g. a server) a recurrent memory leak can lead to [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29): after some time, your process will be using so much memory that it won't fit in your physical memory. This is not a problem per se, because the OS provides [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) but the OS will spend more time moving memory pages from your physical memory to disk than doing useful work. This can affect other processes and it might slow down the system significantly (to the point that it might be better to reboot it).

`3.- What are the problems of getting a segmentation fault (the heap).`

A Segmentation Fault will crash your process. It's not directly related to the usage of the heap, but rather to accessing a memory region that does not belong to your process (because it's not part of its address space or because it was, but it was freed). Depending on what your process was doing, this can cause other problems: for instance, if the process was writing to a file when the crash happened it's very likely that it will end up corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

First, stack means automatic memory and heap means manual memory. There are ways around both, but that's generally a more advanced question.

1. On modern operating systems, your application will crash but the operating system and machine as a whole will continue to function. There are of course exceptions to this rule, but they're (again) a more advanced topic.
2. Allocating from the heap and then not deallocating when you're done just means that your program is still considered to be using the memory even though you're not using it. If left unchecked, your program will fail to allocate memory (out of memory errors). How you handle out-of-memory errors could mean anything from a crash (unhandled error resulting in an unhandled exception or a NULL pointer being accessed and generating a segmentation fault) to odd behavior (caught exception or tested for NULL pointer but no special handling case) to nothing at all (properly handled).

On modern operating systems, the memory will be freed when your application exits.

1. A segmentation fault in the normal sense will simply crash your application. The operating system may immediately close file or socket handles. It may also perform a dump of your application's memory so that you can try to debug it posthumously with tools designed to do that (more advanced subject).

Alternatively, most (I think?) modern operating systems will use a special method of telling the program that it has done something bad. It is then up to the program's code to decide whether or not it can recover from that or perhaps add additional debug information for the operating system, or whatever really.

1. I suggest you look into auto pointers (also called smart pointers) for making your heap behave a little bit like a stack -- automatically deallocating memory when you're done using it. If you're using a modern compiler, see std::unique_ptr. If that type name can't be found, then look into the boost library (google). It's a little more advanced but highly valuable knowledge.

Hope this helps.